# UpdateOrInsert in DB facade

Tags: php, laravel, database

I pass arrays with dates and places to the controller and I want to update or insert records, but if there is no data, then inserting the entire record (date, place, event) is required, but how can I specify some date or place if they are in an array and the check goes over the array and i can't know which value is not found.

```
DB::table('checked_seats')
            ->where('event_id', $event_id)
            ->whereIn('seat', $seat)
            ->whereIn('date', $dates)
            ->updateOrInsert(['price'=>$price]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#update-or-insert):

> Sometimes you may want to update an existing record in the database or
> create it if no matching record exists. In this scenario, the
> updateOrInsert method may be used. The updateOrInsert method accepts
> two arguments: an array of conditions by which to find the record, and
> an array of column and value pairs indicating the columns to be
> updated.
>
> The updateOrInsert method will attempt to locate a matching database
> record using the first argument's column and value pairs. If the
> record exists, it will be updated with the values in the second
> argument. If the record can not be found, a new record will be
> inserted with the merged attributes of both arguments:

So you need to pass it two arrays instead of `where` calls.

Shortened example:

```
DB::table('checked_seats')
             ->updateOrInsert(['event_id'=>$event_id, 'seat'=>$seat], ['price'=>$price]);
```

This will look for an event with the specified event_id and seat. If it exists, the price will be updated. If not, a new entry with all the fields is inserted.